# jQuery select option based on array doesn't work in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a script that selects the highest nearest value from an array and then selects the appropriate option in a hidden select. This is all based on user input.

When a user hits the submit button, then that script needs to get the value from that hidden select.

I managed to get this working (with my limited jQuery knowledge) in all browsers except Safari. Somehow Safari always selects the very first option.

The script itself selects the correct value. I can see in the safari console that the correct option is selected. However when clicking the submit button it still selects the first option.

I've read that I need to use `$(document).on('change'....` however the value need to be grabbed when I hit a button.

So what I have is:

```js
function calculate() {
  /* create array with variants */
  var variants = [];
  $('#product_configure_variants').each(function() {
    variants.push({
      value: $(this).val(),
      size: $(this).data('size'),
      price: $(this).data('price'),
      priceIncl: $(this).data('priceincl')
    });
  });

  /* get highest nearest variant from array if ontwMaat doesn't match */
  var goal = ontwMaat; // a value like 500 or 645 etc
  var closest = null;
  var match = $.grep(variants, function(e) {
    return e.size == goal;
  });
  if (match.length == 0) {
    var minDiff = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;

    for (var index in variants) {
      var valueObject = variants[index];
      if (valueObject.size > goal) {
        var diff = Math.abs(valueObject.size - goal);
        if (diff < minDiff) {
          closest = valueObject;
          minDiff = diff;
        }
      }
    }
  } else if (match.length == 1) {
    closest = match[0]
  }

  // I first unselect all
  $('#product_configure_variants option').removeAttr("selected");

  // Then I select matching value
  $('#product_configure_variants option[value="' + closest['value'] + '"]').attr("selected", "selected")

  // Do I need this below???? 
  //  $('#product_configure_variants').trigger('change');

  // .... more code
}

$(function() {
  $('.addToCartTest').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // .... more code  .....
    var mainFormVariant = $('#product_configure_variants').find('option:selected').val();
    alert(mainFormVariant)
  })
})

// I tried following
$(document).on('change', "#product_configure_variants", function() {
  alert($(this).val())
});

var mainFormVariant = $('#product_configure_variants option:selected').val();
var mainFormVariant = $('#product_configure_variants').find('option:selected').val();

///     .... more code  .....
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="product_configure_variants" name="variant" style="display:none;">
  <option data-size="50 " data-price="3.72" data-priceincl="4.5" value="128428226">50 mm</option>
  <option data-size="100 " data-price="5.5" data-priceincl="6.65" value="128428229">100 mm</option>
  <option data-size="150 " data-price="7.27" data-priceincl="8.8" value="128428232">150 mm</option>
  <option data-size="200 " data-price="9.09" data-priceincl="11" value="128428235">200 mm</option>
  <option data-size="250 " data-price="10.87" data-priceincl="13.15" value="128428238">250 mm</option>
</select>
<a class="addToCartTest" data-loading-text="One moment!"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Submit</a>
```

Comment: And where is your hidden select? And the submit button? Your example snippet runs fine in my Safari.

Comment: @hallleron: You were right I made some typos. I've corrected and changed everything. The `select` is hidden with `display:none;` and it's selected options are set dynamically by the `calculate()` function. So the user can't actually select an option like you would normally do with a select. That value that will be set is `var goal = ontwMaat;`. Where `ontwMaat;` is a value calculated by some text inputs. That all works fine. The problem is that that dynamically set value isn't grabbed when I click the submit button. It always grabs the first option.

Comment: Thank you for updating your topic, however I think I really need some more context related code to see where the calculate() function gets executed etc.

Comment: @hallleron: Ok I've copy/paste the complete script including html and css in a Fiddle. Including a link to a test page where you can see it in action. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/meules/yv96ea5v/2/) I've uncommented code that is not relevant for my question!

Comment: @hallleron: Once again I'm p[retty new to this so probably a lot won't be good or something but my main concern is that it actually works except for that value. I use this as a learning project :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my own problem by removing the dynamic set method of the select and instead created a data attribute. Then in doc.ready I just get the data attribute value and that's all...

```
 // I first unselect all
 // $('#product_configure_variants option').removeAttr("selected");

  // Then I select matching value
//  $('#product_configure_variants option[value="' + closest['value'] + '"]').attr("selected", "selected")

/* set data attr in submit btn */
$('.addToCartTest').attr({ 'data-mfv': closest['value'] })
```